# For loop in r as in python

Tags: python, r, for-loop

Is it possible in R to have a for-loop something like this in Python, with applying two elements (x,y) in a for loop?

```py
for key,value in dict.items():
   print(key, value)
```

Comment: Why a nested loop? I don't understand what you are asking. What, *exactly* are you trying to accomplish in R?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Sorry not to explain my question appropriately, i mean that can we put two items in a for loop at the same time, to print out elements of a dataframe, for example in r coding : for (i,x in df[ , ]) { print(i) print(n)}. Instead of : for (i in length(df)) { for x in nrow(df)) { print(df[x,i]} }.

Comment: i believe you are looking for someting like `mapply()`, like `mapply( function(x,y) paste(x,y), 1:4, 2:5 )`

Comment: @Wimpel, that was a helpful comment, i would write my solution based on your comment with some modification.

Comment: But overall, this python feature seems has not been implemented in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dict_py = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}

## python
# print dictionary elements as paired: 

for x,y in dict_py.items():
    print(x,y)
## a 1
## b 2
## c 3
## d 4

# python allows applying different function to each elements:

t1 = []
t2 = []
for x,y in dict_py.items():
    t1.append(x + "zz")
    t2.append(y**2)


print(t1, t2)

## ['azz', 'bzz', 'czz', 'dzz'] [1, 4, 9, 16]

# dataframe example in R
df <- data.frame(
  first = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  second = c(1,2,3,4)
)

#mapply function to print paired values(paste or print)
#with paste

func1 <-mapply(function(x,y) paste(x,y), df['first'], df['second'])

colnames(func1) <-NULL

print(func1)
##      [,1] 
## [1,] "a 1"
## [2,] "b 2"
## [3,] "c 3"
## [4,] "d 4"

#with print
func2 <- mapply(function(x,y) print(c(x,y)), df[,'first'], df[,'second'])

## [1] "a" "1"
## [1] "b" "2"
## [1] "c" "3"
## [1] "d" "4"

#other example

mapply(function(x,y) print(c(x,y)), df[,'first'], df[,'second'])[0]
## [1] "a" "1"
## [1] "b" "2"
## [1] "c" "3"
## [1] "d" "4"
## character(0)
```

these are the codes i wrote in python and r for comparison, i tried to apply different function to each dataframe elements by mapply but it does not work properly.
But for applying x,y simaltaneously it worked, thanks to @Wimpel for helpful comment.

Actually this is not a problematic issue for me, and what i wrote in question was just an example of this feature in python.  but if such feature was in r, it could fascilitate coding somehow.

Comment: Please post code as **code** (i.e. using text in a code block), not as an image! Images are completely inaccessible to search, and to visually impaired people ...

Comment: @Ben Bolker, ok your right, i posted it in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3,4)
  , y = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  print(df$y[i])
}
```

or the second option?

```
df <- list(
  x = c(1,2,3,4)
  , y = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
)

for (i in 1:length(df$x)){
  print(paste(df[['x']][i], df[['y']][i]))
}
```

Comment: @Roeof Waaijman, your code prints out just y column. What i meant was to print each pair next to each other, outside of dataframe .

Comment: @Roeof Waaijman, Thanks for your answers, but my question was about (x,y), both elements in 'for loop', means: for (x,y in df), not one element(for (x in df)).  It is not a problematic issue for me,  but if some capability like this was in r, may be it could make some code lines shorter and easier.